# Self-answer based on someone else's poor question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Last month, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797168/how-to-approach-this-type-of-problem-in-permutation-and-combination) was posted on Stack Overflow. I thought it was a fascinating question but did not give an answer since I thought the question was very poor for these reasons.

1. The question was an active competition question, on hackerearth.com, "Altitudes" in the June Circuits '19 series of questions.
2. The question originally was basically just a link to a graphic showing the question. The graphic was not needed, since the question is originally given entirely in text. When I asked the OP to give the question in text, he added a brief summary of the question that was somewhat incorrect.
3. The OP showed absolutely no work of his own. When asked to show some work he gave the excuse "I have no idea how to solve this problem."
4. When I pointed out in comments the weaknesses in his question, he only added the summary, stated he would do better in the future, and kept asking for an answer.

It seemed clear that the OP was looking for a lazy way to solve a competition question, so I voted to close. I also worked out some code for the question, code that is not obvious. The competition ended on June 30 so that issue is gone. I do not want to answer such a poor question, though apparently not many people agree that the question is so poor and the question has not been closed. The answers in the competition do not appear to be available to non-members of that site (I have not seen any of those answers), so my answer would add something new to the internet, not just to this site. Clearly the question is interesting, since it was in a competition and others did answer within the competition.

My question: **Is is appropriate for me to ask a new question on Stack Overflow, copying the old question but typing the question as text and linking to the original question, and self-answer my question?** I do not see anything about this reason for a new question and self-answer in any question on meta or in Stack Overflow's documentation (such as [this item](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). My solution is fairly complicated and I would love to see better answers from others.

---

**Conclusion:** Due to the answer and some comments, I have decided not to start my own question. Instead, I edited the question and gave an answer. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Appropriate? eh, depends on how you do it. Just keep in mind it has to follow all the same guidelines as other questions yada yada subject to closure/voting etc

Comment: @KevinB: I guess I am concerned about being accused of plagiarism. I also know that self-answer questions tend to attract down-votes just for being self-answers. This would be my first question on StackOverflow--all my other possible questions were answered by myself during research so I never asked.

Comment: What are hackerearth's policies on sharing content it posts?

Comment: @KevinB: I did not see any relevant statement in my exploration of the site. I did not join the site--something I am always reluctant to do--so my exploration was limited.

Comment: You'd also need to find a way to frame the question such that it isn't just a requirement dump in search of an answer, given the image... that might take some work.

Comment: @KevinB: Wouldn't self-answering right away handle that issue?

Comment: I'm not seeing much of a programming question there either... It's tagged `math`, which raises all kinds of red flags with me. Yes, technically, algorithms are on topic here, but they need to be programming-related.

Comment: @RoryDaulton well, no. An answer does not make a question complete/good/on topic. (well... unless the answer is by the author of curl apparently)

Comment: @HereticMonkey: The question asks for a program. It gives a specific input format for the code and I believe the competition used an automatic checker on any code answer. I believe the `math` tag just means that math would be needed in the algorithm. I did use Bezout's theorem and some other math in my code. My answer definitely is a program--more lengthy than I would like.

Comment: Side note: I'd be very concerned posting an answer to someone else likely copyrighted assignment... There is non-zero chance of request to remove the content (especially after discussion on meta) which take your answer with it... I like [Servy's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387365/477420) - see if you can pick part that is on-topic plus generally useful and ask/answer just that. "Write code for this random assignment" is rarely fares well on SO (again, especially when you shine meta light on your plans).

Comment: How-to questions are not inherently off-topic and they do not require an attempt to solve the problem. Your reasoning for voting to close the question is faulty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not appropriate to re-post a question just so that you can put the content of an image as text.  If you think that the question would be improved by having the text in that image written as text in the post, just *edit that question*.  That's an entirely reasonable change to make as an edit.

Now if you read a question that was unclear, confusing, missing lots of important information, or brought up a topic that seemed interesting but did not ask a question you found useful on that topic, or anything along those lines, and reading that question has inspired you to write a new question that was similar to, or otherwise inspired from a *different question*, then by all means, ask that.

Comment: Consider to add remark about appropriate license/attribution for re-posting content (in this case someone else competition).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well I'm advocating they *not* just re-post the content.  Or do you just mean that's an additional reason not to re-post the content, in which case, sure.

Comment: Just as additional reason why it is bad idea for the particular question (as original likely can't be fixed either so editing as you suggest in first part is out). Totally agree that new cleaned up and well scoped question is good approach in general and probably only one acceptable route here.

Comment: I seem to be getting conflicting advice--edit the question by converting the graphic to text then answering it, or not doing so since it may be copyrighted. I have decided not to post my own question, but which is better for the existing question?

Comment: @RoryDaulton images if a question are not acceptable - so you must to replace the image with text.  Separately if content is not your own you need to add appropriate attribution (should have been done already... but no one cared to edit). Unrelated to both publishing on SO means content should be compatible with CC BY-SA3 license... quoting small portions of content with other licenses may be ok, posting whole pages of content under incompatible license is questionable but IANAL - use your own judgement.